# What are the 'Movement', 'Work' and 'Category' sections in the Music app and how do I set them?

Tags: music.app

I went through some of the View options (<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>) in the Music app and noticed three sections that I can't seem to set through a song's Info panel (<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>).

Here's an overview of them:
[image]

1. Green arrows. First one, seems self-explanatory, *Movement Number* and *Movement Name* seem to be settings one would use primarily with classical music. I can set both to show in the song list view (the view in my screenshot), but I can't seem to set them via the song's Info panel, which I normally use to enter the data, unless I'm overlooking something. In addition, I can only set *Movement Name* in the song list view by clicking in the area under it. I can't do the same for *Movement Number*. While a song is highlighted, you can actually tab-cycle through some of these fields, but that won't hit *Movement Number*.
2. Blue arrows. *Grouping* and *Work* seems to be duplicated. While I can set *Grouping* in the Info panel, I can't seem to set *Work* there. I think during the iTunes times Apple envisaged *Grouping* to cluster songs that belong together, which is often the case in classical music. In the example I have grouped titles 1–4 and 5–11 together. *Work* seems to duplicate whatever I've entered under *Grouping* and, again, I can't enter *Work* through the Info panel, though I can edit them in the song list view. I'm aware that all these fields can be used as the user pleases, but would be curious to know what the idea behind these were.
3. Red arrows. The *Category* field is the strangest to me, because not only does it not appear in the Info panel, but you also can't edit it through the song list view and, I have not idea what it's for or meant to show.